# Fazer requisição em uma página com Guzzle

Tags: php, web-crawler, guzzle

Estou com problema ao fazer uma requisição POST em um site através do componente [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle).
O site alvo é :http://ciagri.iea.sp.gov.br/nia1/subjetiva.aspx?cod_sis=1&idioma=1

Ele até chega a entrar no site mas não aparece nenhum resultado.
Não sei se o problema está em **COMO** faço a requisição ou se é os **PARÂMETROS** que passo.

Alguém saberia dizer o que está errado

Código:

```
<?php
use GuzzleHttp\Client; 
$client = new Client();
        //Padrão para as requisições
        $headers = [
            'headers' =>
                [
                    'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36',
                    'Accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                    'Accept-Language' => 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
                    'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate',
                    'Referer' => 'http://ciagri.iea.sp.gov.br/nia1/subjetiva.aspx?cod_sis=1&idioma=1',
                    'Origin' => 'http://ciagri.iea.sp.gov.br',
                    'Host' => 'ciagri.iea.sp.gov.br',
                    'Connection' => 'keep-alive'
                ]
        ];
        //Parâmetros para a primeira requisição
        $body = [
            'body' =>
                [
                    'cmbAno_Inicial' => '1983',
                    'cmbAno_Final'=>'2014',
                    'cmbRegiao'=>'EDR',
                    'chkRegiao$0'=>'on',
                    'chkPerg$69'=>'on',
                    'imgPesquisar.x'=>'67',
                    'imgPesquisar.y'=>'20',
                    'cmbTpSaida'=>'RA'

                ]
        ];

        //Primeira requisição, passamos a consulta
        $param = array_merge($body, $headers);
        $request = $client->createRequest('POST', 'http://ciagri.iea.sp.gov.br/nia1/subjetiva.aspx?cod_sis=1&idioma=1', $param);
        $retorno=$client->send($request);
        $corpo=$retorno->getBody();
        echo $corpo;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltam vários parâmetros.

Você chegou nessa lista de parâmetros olhando o formulário HTML? Esse método é trabalhoso e sujeito a falhas. Recomendo fazer isso observando a aba Network das Ferramentas do Desenvolvedor do Chrome ou similar nos outros navegadores.

Pelo que eu vi, faltam os parâmetros:

```
__EVENTTARGET
__EVENTARGUMENT
__LASTFOCUS
__VIEWSTATE
__EVENTVALIDATION
txtAgrupamento
```

Note que alguns desses parâmetros (__VIEWSTATE e __EVENTVALIDATION, a princípio) parecem ser uma espécie de token CSRF.

Isso significa que você vai ter que fazer um pedido GET da página de consulta antes, para obter esses parâmetros que são gerados ali. Extraia esses parâmetros do HTML e inclua na sua próxima requisição POST - essa sim trará os resultados da consulta.

Comment: poderia me dar um exemplo? Pois na própria url já tem parametros que são obtidos por GET

Comment: Mesmo com esses parâmetros GET da URL, faltam-lhe os que eu citei. Olhe no código fonte da página de consulta, repare que há `<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="..." />`, além dos outros que eu já listei pra você.